# Facebook status updates / calendar events

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Is there a plugin (that I can use on my website) available that I can just plug in, and all of my page's updates stream through to the page I put it on?

I've tried: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/ and the "Like Box"... isn't necessarily what I'm looking for... I want more of a stream of status updates to use in a "News and updates" column on my website (that I don't want to actually update on my own). Preferably if I can style it on my own too.

The other side of this is the calendar events. My facebook page has events that I have created, and I'm wondering if I can use the events on this page, to sync back (like I'm wanting the status updates to, also) to another column on my website... rather than using another calendar such as Google to provide my users with events. Would be much easier to just go through Facebook.

Are there plugins out there for this? I've been up and down Google trying to find something and haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Localized problem. Use their API to build a custom solution.